# html element pattern from json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pattern-matching

I developing small application using Angularjs in that behaviour of the feilds are coming from the server in json format.
**Issue:** The pattern fromat which i am getting is in string format because of that pattern matching is not working.

I found one solution like after getting json data I has to change the string into Regexp. but it will increase uI load. 
Since i am assining the pattern directly to the tag . **Is there any other solutions**

```
EX:   my json looks like"feildBehaviour": {
    "feild1": {
       "pattern": "/^[A-z]+$/",
         .......          
    },feild2 ...................

 <input type="text" ng-pattern="page1.fieldname.pattern"/> where I am directly assining pattern to the feild. is there any way solve this issue.
```

Thanks

Comment: From Angular docs:

"If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly. If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters. For instance, "abc" will be converted to new RegExp('^abc$')."

Maybe your example does not work because it already contains ^ and $?

Comment: Can you try this? 
{ "pattern": "[A-z]+" }